# Send String second Argument IdentifierGenerator - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have implemented a custom generator, for my application and I want to send a string as the second argument to the IdentifierGenerator interface but I am not getting any clue how to do this. unfortunately because fo the below code, it is setting null2 as the key generated. please help.

I want to send a String which is the "date" from the client as the second argument.

Thanks.

```
public class CourierTransImpl implements IdentifierGenerator{
private String appendString;
@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object arg1)
        throws HibernateException {
     Connection connection = session.connection();
     int id=0;
        try {

            PreparedStatement ps = connection
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(TRANS_ID) as value from SecurePass.COURIER_TRANSACTIONS_SER_TABLE");

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                id = rs.getInt("value");
               id++;
            }
            ps = connection
                    .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SecurePass.COURIER_TRANSACTIONS_SER_TABLE VALUES("+id+")");
            ps.execute();
        } catch (SQLException e) {       
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return appendString+id;
}
public String getAppendString() {
    return appendString;
}
public void setAppendString(String appendString) {
    this.appendString = appendString;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the [Configurable](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/id/Configurable.html) interface and override the [configure](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/id/Configurable.html#configure%28org.hibernate.type.Type,%20java.util.Properties,%20org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect%29) for your requirement. By doing this you can only pass a static value as a parameter to `CourierTransImpl` class

If you want to pass some dynamic values then you can have a `@Transient` property defined in your entity and then access that property in your `CourierTransImpl` class.

**Detailed explanation:**

For example, lets says there is an entity called `Employee` and it has a transient property called `empType` then you can define the entity like this.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UniqueIdGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UniqueIdGenerator", strategy = "com.CourierTransImpl", 
    parameters = { @Parameter(name = "appendString", value = "Emp") })
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @Transient
    private String empType;

   // Getters & Setters
}
```

In above code you can see that we set the parameter `appendString` and this is a static value that we are setting here as "Emp".

Now the `CourierTransImpl` class that implements Configurable interface:

```
public class CourierTransImpl implements IdentifierGenerator, Configurable {

private String appendString;

@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
        throws HibernateException {
    Connection connection = session.connection();
    int id = 0;
    try {
        Employee emp = (Employee) object;
        id = ..; // your logic to get the id from database

        // Now you can use the parameter appendString which is static value set to "Emp"
       // You can also access any of the employee properties here, so in your code you can set the required value dynamically.
        return appendString + emp.getEmpType()+id;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return appendString + id;
}

@Override
public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect d)
        throws MappingException {
    setAppendString(params.getProperty("appendString")); // Here we are setting the parameters.
}

// Setters & Getters
```

}

In this example if I create an object of `Employee` and set the `empType` to some value say "Manager", then the hibernate generates and id like "Emp1Manager".

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but the reason it is showing `null2` is that your `appendString` is null and not initialized.I guess you need to set the appendString to the date.

Comment: actually this should be a comment to the question rather than an answer.

Comment: If you study the text of the question it is clearly understood. Now I do not even need `appendString`