# Hibernate IdGenerator database schema

Tags: java, hibernate

After reading this article:
[Send String second Argument IdentifierGenerator - Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755942/send-string-second-argument-identifiergenerator-hibernate)
I have a question how can i pass schema name to IdGenerator?
Is it possible to get access to spring configuration of hibernate?

so i could read schema name and correctly form SQL queries like that:

```
        final Connection connection = sessionImplementor.connection();

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM "+shemaName+".cbr_seqnr WHERE seqnr_name =?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1,seqName);
        }
```